# Jquery single validation form in multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have 3 fields I want to validate validate all 3 fields and allow the form to be submitted if a minimum of one field is filled. I am unable to do that.

Please  check my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){  
        $("#field1").validate({
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
             message: "Please enter username!",
        });                
         $("#field2").validate({
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
             message: "Please enter username!",
        });
        $("#field3").validate({
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
             message: "Please enter username!",
        });

    });          
 </script>
```

HTML-

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="field1" />  <!-- username1 -->
  <input type="text" id="field2" />  <!-- username2 -->
  <input type="text" id="field3" />  <!-- username3 -->
  <input type="submit id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the above code, the validation requires all fields to be filled. But my requirement is only one field needs to be filled. If I leave all fields, then the message "Please enter username!" will show.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u24c1nw/1)

Comment: Is `.validate()` a plugin or your own method? Perhaps you can set this up as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: No i am using `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validation.functions.js`

Comment: Please check http://myshowcam.com/TestSite/js/jquery.validate.js   and         http://myshowcam.com/TestSite/js/jquery.validation.functions.js

Comment: There's not enough info here for us to answer. Maybe one of those plugins already has the ability to do as you require. Could you give those fields the same `name` or class? `$("input[name='username']").validate({...`. WHY do you have 3 fields for the same thing anyway!?

Comment: this can also be done by just a jquery code, there's no need to add a plugin for this.. to achieve it you can write the code as `$("input[type=text]").each(function(){ if($(this).val().length > 0) alert('user has inputted');  })`. For checking you can store the lengths in a array and check if any value is greater than 0 then proceed for submit else show message :)

Comment: @Moob please check http://jsfiddle.net/3u24c1nw/

Comment: @Moob i have updated my code with css please check - http://jsfiddle.net/3u24c1nw/1/

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements , check it out :

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" />  <!-- username1 -->
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" />  <!-- username2 -->
    <input type="text" id="field3" name="field3" />  <!-- username3 -->
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm()
    {
        field1=$('#field1').val();
        field2=$('#field2').val();
        field3=$('#field3').val();

        if(field1 == '' && field2 == '' && field3 == '')
        {
            alert('Please fill atleast one field.');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```